# Adding Items in a listbox visual basic

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm making a cash register for homework and all the transactions are listed in a listbox (the amount)

Now I know how to add this up using a for loop, but the course has not even gone into loops yet so If i use loops I might lose marks

For example

55.34

43.13

12.43

The only way I can think of adding all these up to get the total is using a for loop, since I do not know how many transactions will be there.

Maybe there is a listbox function that I do not know of?

This is how items are added to the listbox

```
  Private Sub enterTaxable_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles enterTaxable.Click
    conversion = textDollars.Text + "." + textCents.Text
    taxable = CDbl(conversion) 
    tax = taxable * 0.07
    taxable = tax + taxable
    taxable = FormatNumber(taxable, 2)
    salesSlip.Items.Add(taxable)
    textDollars.Text = ""
    textCents.Text = ""
End Sub
```

salesSlip is my listbox name

Comment: You can get the [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx) in the listbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no function of the the `ListBox` control to facilitate this for you, and any control that will is going to be very specific and even less common than the knowledge of loops that you report hasn't been taught yet; therefore, you're in he same predicament!

Use a loop.

If your teacher hasn't given the means you need otherwise, then approach them about it and enquire.

Comment: I already asked him 4 days ago no reply and it's due tomorrow. Think I'm just gonna go ahead with using loops since there appears to be no special function, or at least it's not within the reach

Comment: @user2472706: Looping is fundamental to programming and with the exception of outputting text to a console should come right at the start of a beginning programming class. It may be that you'll be expected to do some independent study to get your assignments done, which may be indicated by the lack of a response from your professor.